# Hide a table column in a nested ListView

Tags: asp.net, html, listview

I have a ListView inside another ListView, and I'd like to hide a table column in the inner ListView whenever a particular parameter is passed. Given the setup below, how would I hide the ID column (both the header and the data) if the URL contains "...?id=no"?

```
<asp:ListView ID="ProcedureListView" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h4>
            <%#Eval("PROCEDURE_CODE") %>
        </h4>
        <asp:ListView ID="BenefitListView" runat="server" DataSource='<%#Eval("benefits") %>'>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="5" class="indent">
                    <tr class="tableHeader">
                        <td>
                            ID
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Benefit
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%#Eval("benefit_id")%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#Eval("benefit_name")%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are trying to do this from the code behind then you could do this:

On the onBind event for the outer ListView you would find the inner listview control, and then find the label you want and change the visible property to false. i answered this on your other question.

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

you could wrap them in a placeholder and then dynamically set the visibility of the placeholder to remove the column... (you will need two placeholders)

Comment: I'm having trouble with the dynamic part. If I wrap it in a placeholder named "myPH", then do ProcedureListView.FindControl("myPH"), it returns nothing.

Comment: can you post your code behind? how are you databinding your nested ListView?

Comment: My bad - instead I should have been stepping through the items collection, since each inner control exists on each row (item).

Answer (score 0):

you could do the following:

```
<% if (Request.QueryString["id"] != "no") { %>
   <td>
     <%#Eval("benefit_id")%>
   </td>
<% } %>
   <td>
     <%#Eval("benefit_name")%>
   </td>
```

and do the same for the header.

edit: you are not clear but from a previous comment, if you want to do this in the code behind then you should place the id header and the id data in a label server control. then you can check the query string in the code behind, and on data bind you could set the visible property to false.

there are a few options here, it really depends on what you are most comfortable with.

Comment: Unfortunately, when you try to do that in the header, it produces this error: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: Edit reply: The problem is that this is a nested ListView, so I can't access anything inside it from the code behind. If this were just a simple ListView, there would be a number of ways to do it, but they all seem to fall down in the nested ListView.

Comment: you mean the designer throws an error right? so that only means you have to edit the code in the html view. it should run properly, though i havent tried it.

Comment: you might want to indicate what you have tried so far, so the answers are not redundant.

Answer (score 0):

add a css class to the HTML tags and from code behind inject the css class onto the page like so

```
<td id='' class='hideMe'> 
    ID
</td>
```

code behind, in the pre-render event

```
if(id==123){
   // please refer to help file for exact syntax
   // but essentially you will be injecting
   // <style type='text/css'>
   // .hideMe{display:none;}
   // </style>
}
```

Alternatively, you can include the above css class in your stylesheet and only add it to the tags you want hidden based on the ID